# Convert image from (28,28,4) to 2D flat array and write to csv

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, neural-network

The following code successfully converts an image file to a numpy array, and then back to an image.

```
with open(BASE_DIR + '/web/images/testImage.png') as file:
    img = Image.open(file)
    pixels = numpy.asarray(img)
    img = Image.fromarray(pixels)
    img.show()
```

Great. Bueno. Awesome.

The image is `(28, 28)`. However, when I convert the image to a numpy array, the dimensions are `(28, 28, 4)`.

To resize the pixels so they are (28, 28), I add the line below:

```
with open(BASE_DIR + '/web/images/testImage.png') as file:
    img = Image.open(file)
    pixels = numpy.asarray(img)
    pixels = numpy.resize(pixels, (28,28))  # this line here!!!
    img = Image.fromarray(pixels)
    img.show()
```

However, when I show the image, it's all distorted and messed up.

My goal is to resize the 2D multichannel image (28, 28, 4) to a flat (28, 28) image array and write the pixel data to csv.

How can I A) read the (28, 28) image as numpy pixel data that represents a true (28, 28) array, or B) resize the numpy array so that the image doesn't get distorted when written to a csv?

This gist contains my current code and data uri I've been playing with:

https://gist.github.com/daino3/b671b2d171b3948692887e4c484caf47

#### EDIT:

When I convert the image to black and white with:

```
with open(BASE_DIR + '/web/images/testImage_1502036630.png') as file:
    img = Image.open(file).convert('L')  # convert to B&W
    img.show()
```

I lose all pixel data values and the image is entirely black.

Comment: The (28,28,4) array has 4x as much information as the (28,28,1) one.  Do you want to loose that?

Comment: Even if your image is (28, 28, 4) the image size in pixels is still 28 x 28. The other 4 dimensions are just RGB-A information. Is therefore impossible to write exactly a 28x28x4 data into 28x28 CSV table. The only option you have is to transform the image to grayscale (but you would lose information as @hpaulj mentions).

Comment: Gents, RGBA data loss is fine - I should have specified that in my question. It's a black and white image.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your image is in `RGBa` mode. Try:

```
img = Image.open(file).convert('L')
```

Comment: I will try this out tonight. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I tried your solution above, and was not successful. Any additional ideas?

Comment: @daino3 used the following image to test proposed solution: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/imgcomp-440x330.png and it worked for me. I do not have your image to see what exactly is going on there.

Comment: @daino3 Maybe try this: `img = Image.open(file).convert('LA'); pixels = numpy.asarray(img)[:,:,0] # ignore/drop alpha`